# access data from one class to other c#

Tags: c#

I have a class which talks to a wcf

```
public class Network
{
    private const string PROXY_HOSTNAME_PARAM = "ProxyHostname";        
    public string GetMyNetwork()
    {
        MyProxy myprox = MyProxy.Instance;
        string network = string.Empty;
        network = myprox .GetNetworkConfig(); 
        return network;
    }
```

Now  i have another class where I create object of the class Network and invoke GetMyNetwork() to get network.
When i do this it hits wcf again and gives me the string. I want to avoid that.I want it to cache the network string once and for all and whenever i hit this method i should get the data without hitting wcf again. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: You could use cache, static variable, save to db, save to file, etc.

Comment: One word: Singleton

Comment: ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if(cache.Contains(network))
            return (IEnumerable)cache.Get(network);

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Network
{
    private const string PROXY_HOSTNAME_PARAM = "ProxyHostname";    
    private string network = String.Empty;  
    private Network _instance; 
    public string GetMyNetwork()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(network))
        {
           MyProxy myprox = MyProxy.Instance;
           network = myprox .GetNetworkConfig(); 
        }
        return network;
    }
    private Network() { }
    public Network Instance
    {
       get
       {
          if (this._instance == null)
          {
              this._instance = new Network();
          }
          return this._instance;
       }
    }     
}
```

Make sure to maintain only one instance of `Network` class. Each time you create a new instance of `Network` class, the internal network variable will be a blank string, so calling `GetMyNetwork` method will again call the WCF service.

Comment: didnt help when i create a object of this class and call my method it hits wcf again

Comment: @sameer Whenever you call the method on a new instance of this class, it will hit the WCF. You should maintain a single instance of this class throughout the client application e.g. you could make a static variable or make the Network class singleton.

Comment: @sameer I have made this class singleton. Try to invoke the method like Network.Instance.GetMyNetwork(); This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Rocker1985 That's not even close to singleton. Thing you've done is preventing `Network` object from being instantiated with `new Network()` making it useless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set class and function( or property) static

```
public static MyClass
{
    public static string MyFunc()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

usage

```
string myString = MyClass.MyFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make singleton from your `Network` class :

```
public class Network
{
    static Network _instance;

    public static Network Instance
    {
         get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Network()); }
    }

    string _networkString;

    private Network() { _networkString = string.Empty; }

    public string GetMyNetwork()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_networkString))
            return (_networkString = MyProxy.Instance.GetNetworkConfig());

        return _networkString;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to use it the same way as you use your `MyProxy` object :

```
string network = Network.Instance.GetMyNetwork();
```